# Python web scraping : how to skip url error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape a webpage ("coinmarketcap"). I am scraping data from 2013 to 2019 October (Open, High, Low, Close, Marketcap, Volume) of all cryptocurrencies.

```
for j in range (0,name_size):
   url = ("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/" + str(name[j]) + "/historical-data/?start=20130429&end=20191016")
   page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

   soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

   priceDiv = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'table-responsive'})
rows = priceDiv.find_all('tr')
```

The problem is some url doesn't exist. And I don't know how to skip those. Can you please help me?

Comment: Handle an exception using `try` and `except`, write a part that raised an error in `try` and `except` exception and do nothing there write pass to ignore except or you can write code that does something when an error raised

Comment: can you give an example of a working url and a failing url please?

Answer (score 1):

Use `try-except`

```
for j in range (0,name_size):
   url = ("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/" + str(name[j]) + "/historical-data/?start=20130429&end=20191016")
   try: 
       page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
       soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
       priceDiv = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'table-responsive'})
   except:
       print("Coult not open url")

rows = priceDiv.find_all('tr')
```

Answer (score 0):

use error catching.

```
try: 
    #do the thing
except Exception as e:
    #here you can print the error
```

The ones in error will simply be skipped wit the print message, else the task continues